# Doctrine migration issue. Windows->linux, MySQL 5.5->MySQL 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine program that works great on my development machine but when I move it to my server, it stops working.  The main differences between the two machines are one is windows and running mySql 5.5 and the other is linux running MySQL 5.1.

I have pinpointed the failure to the line $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($dql, $rsm) as the log statement afterwords never occurs.

```
get_log()->logDebug("query: ".$dql);
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->entityManager);
get_log()->logDebug("ResultSetMappingBuilder");

var_dump($rsm);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('D_Post', 'f');
get_log()->logDebug("addRootEntityFromClassMetadata");
$query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($dql, $rsm);
get_log()->logDebug("createNativeQuery");
```

The sql that is running is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT f.ID,f.post_title, f.post_date, f.post_type,
f.views_count
as score FROM wp_vsideviewpostfilter f  ) t ORDER BY t.score DESC,t.post_title 
DESC  LIMIT 0,10
```

I can execute the SQL code on the linux machine via a query runner and it executes correctly.

Any ideas as to why this program is failing on the other server?

Comment: check PHP and MySQL error logs for traces.

Comment: Since you are developing in Windows and testing in Linux, maybe the problem is case-sensitive related? Happened to me a few times :D

Comment: I don't know why I forgot to check the actual server log.  I did have an issue with case sensitivity earlier but solved that one already.  However, this was issue was with mixing \ and / in a directory path.  For some reason, windows allows this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue was with one of the mappings.  Doctrine could not find the D_Post entity mapping.  The path to the mapping had a mixture of / and \ in it which is allowed in windows but not in linux.